# How to query the datastore to get child objects and compare their properties using Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am implementing a project on the google app engine. I would like to query the datastore to refer to the child object's property and use it to identify the parent object.

Think of these as the parent and child classes I am talking about:

```
class Parent {  
String name;  
Child child;  
}      

class Child{  
String id;  
}
```

I need to create a query on the `Parent` objects such that it takes the `id` property from the `Child` (which is in `Parent`) and use it to identify the `Parent` object I need.
I know how bad the design is, but please tell me a way to do this. I would love to use the App Engine Datastore queries, but if not possible I'm open to the Java JDO queries too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at

[GAE Java persistence blog: executing simple joins](http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/executing-simple-joins-across-owned.html)

I believe that I used the information there to tackle the kind of problem you have.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I used the query given in the site and it doesn't throw any errors and unfortunately, no results either. I'll work on it for a few hours and reply soon. Please hang on to this thread!

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. But is there a way to do this with the  App Engine Datastore Queries? I know there is no provision for a JOIN query in that API, but is there another way to do it?

Comment: I don't know. I access the GAE datastore using JDO only, not the GAE datastore API. A work-around could be to make your parent-child relationship bi-directional. Another work-around could be to store the parent entity key (EK) in each child, and query the parent EKs in the children for the set of children you require.